# How to render props inside of route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to use Render inside route but it not working, I tried to use element instead of render but it not work  ?

How to fix this Error ?  :
Matched leaf route at location "/cart" does not have an element. This means it will render an  with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page .

```
/... 
<Route path="/cart" 
render={(props) => <ShoppingCart  {...props}  product={this.state.product}  />}/>

/...
```

Comment: What library and version are you using?

Comment: I use   {
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.2.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },

Comment: `react-router-dom` removed `render` in version 6. Replace it with `element` and pass element directly without a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

react-router-dom removed render in version 6. Replace it with element and pass element directly without a function
–
Konrad Linkowski

```
 <Route path="/cart" 
            element={<ShoppingCart  {...this.props}  product={this.state.product}  />}/>
```